# Should shell aliases be substituted when parsed or when executed?

Tags: bash, shell

Consider the script:

```
alias al='echo A'
foo(){ echo $(al);}
alias al='echo B'
foo
```

bash, ksh, and zsh prints `B`, while dash and yash prints `A`.

Which is correct? Or both?

According to the [POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) (Vol. Shell & Utilities) [2.3.1 Alias Substitution](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03_01),

> After a token has been delimited, but before applying the grammatical rules in [Shell Grammar](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10), a resulting word that is identified to be the command name word of a simple command shall be examined to determine whether it is an unquoted, valid alias name.

It seems aliases should be resolved when the function id defined, as you don't know this is in a function before applying the grammatical rules. However, this doesn't make much sense to me, as you can't identify a word to be the command name word ebfore applying the grammatical rules, either.

Comment: You've surely noticed, when looking up POSIX chapter-and-verse, that aliases are an optional interactive extension. Use other than by a human interactively typing commands is thus outside the designed-for common case.

Comment: That said, _in the interactive case_, aliases can expand to syntax, so any shell that defers expansion in functions is going to have programmatic and interactive use differ. That's probably fine, though, since this is -- again -- outside the designed-for use case.